# Property of moderately decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is said of moderate decrease if there is a $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{M}{1 + |x|^{\alpha}}$, for some $\alpha > 1$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

During solving one exercise I come to a stage where I want $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x+h)-f(x)| d x \rightarrow 0 \text { as } h \rightarrow 0$$
where $f$ is moderately decresing and continous.

How to show that? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Divide the integral into two parts: "near" 0 and far away from $0$. That is, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose  $L$ so that $\int_{L}^\infty M / (1+x^2) \, dx < \epsilon$ (or $\epsilon / k$ for some $k$ TBD.). Then use the fact that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous to choose $h$ so that $f(x+h) - f(x)$ is small enough on $[-L, L]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convergence is true whenever $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Note that $1/(1+|x|^{\alpha})\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $\alpha>n$.

The rough proof of the convergence:

One can use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to show for $f\in C_{0}$, the continuous functions with compact support.

Now approximate $f\in L^{1}$ by a function $\varphi\in C_{0}$, using the standard $\epsilon/3$ argument.

I believe that the in MSE there are many solutions to the proof of the convergence.